# How to find out all the points that line on the line between say {X=569,Y=71} {X=735,Y=91}

Tags: math, line, equation

i am find out the slope here and then coming up with the equation of the line and then incrementing x in steps of 1 and finding out y .

but some how the points generated dont seem to be correct. i am using

(y-y1)=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)(x-x1) for the equation of the line. Am i missing something ?

Comment: You need to increment `x` and `y` alternately. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm for how to determine which to increment when.

Comment: Besides the issue that the "mathematical" method of plotting a line is extremely inefficient, what's the problem?  Do you get "jaggies"?  or are the coordinates you get completely off?  Here's an interesting link, if you're not already familiar with DDA algorithms:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: This should be a math question; but anyway first you have to obtain the slope (how steep is the line) and afterwards you begin changing the values so that you may get the right points; NOTICE THAT THE SLOPE NOT ALWAYS IMPLIES A CHANGE OF 1

Comment: You should add some .NET/C# code that illustrates what you have already, otherwise, this is a "gimme teh codez" question, which is "not a real question", *or* more suitable for http://math.stackexchange.com, as it's pure mathematics.

Comment: @casperOne: I disagree that it's a pure math question.  Perhaps it wasn't worded as well as it should have been, but that seems worth downvoting more than unilaterally closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're computing the slope using an integer divide.

The link Gabe gave in the comments to the Bresenham line algorithm will illustrate a purely integer solution that's fast and efficient.

If you're OK using floating point, compute the slope as a floating point type.  If the line is steep, you probably want to increment in y instead of x.  Either way, compute one coordinate as a floating point number using the slope and the other coordinate that you're stepping.  Then round (correctly) to the nearest integer.

Comment: Rounding can be done with integer divisions: `round(a/b) = (2a + b)/2b`

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy: "Gabe and Paul".  It's coincidental we both cited the same link, at the same time :)  The key issue is jclozano's comment: in integer space, THE SLOPE DOESN'T ALWAYS IMPLY A CHANGE OF 1.

Comment: Regret to say this . we scrapped this idea. it was an inefficient way of doing it ..